# How do I show a div during mouseover event that persists if mouse focuses on new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

Suppose I have a `div` that I bind a `.mouseover` function to that displays another `div` on top of it (of which, may exceed the size of the original `div`). Is it possible to keep the second `div` shown without any noticeable blink during the `.mouseover` transition?

I am using jQuery 1.11 with mostly SVG elements on Chrome.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nvjqdn0j/10/

Comment: If *Suppose I have* means that you already have some code, please provide the relevant code, or maybe create a http://jsfiddle.net to show what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want a div to simply display and stay displayed when you mouse over? http://jsfiddle.net/nvjqdn0j/

Comment: Does the SVG load on mouseover or is that the element with the mouseover event?

Comment: @VictorioBerra Yes - I need it to stay displayed and be able to have it's own elements inside for use (say, an input box). This div can be hidden once my mouse leaves both the floating div, and the div below it.

Comment: @below9k The SVG is the element with the mouseover event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/nvjqdn0j/12/).

```
$("#display, #mouseOverElement").mouseover(function () {
 $("#mouseOverElement").css("visibility", "visible");
});

$("#display, #mouseOverElement").mouseout(function () {
 $("#mouseOverElement").css("visibility", "collapse");
});
```

Now the div keeps displayed as long as the mouse is over `#display` and / or `#mouseOverElement`.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I was looking for. I'll test serverside tomorrow and see I can replicate this